# Change layout content with pointers in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to change the content of a layout with pointers?

I want to do something like the following.

In the header:

```
QWidget* activeView;
QWidget* one;
QWidget* two;
...
```

In the source file I set up the Widgets in the constructor, and push the first to the layout:

```
activeView = one;
ui->activeLayout->addWidget(activeView);
```

And later with slots or methods I want to change the `activeView`:

```
activeView = two;
```

I tried this, but it won't work. I even called the `update()` method of the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work unfortunately.

What you want is `QStackedWidget`. Official documentation is [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

If you don't want to use this widget and want to do it manually, you will have to reconstruct the layout by yourself in code. It can be wrapped in a method and won't be too ugly.

**Example:**

```
void clearLayout(QLayout *layout) 
{
    if (layout) {
        while(layout->count() > 0){
            QLayoutItem *item = layout->takeAt(0);
            delete item->widget();
            delete item;
        }
    }
}

void setNewWidgetVisible(QWidget *activeView)
{
   clearLayout(ui->activeLayout);
   ui->activeLayout->addWidget(activeView);
}
```

Comment: But why won't this work? I thought maybe because the content of the widget is copied or handled in a certain way, but then I suppose it should reboulild itself when explicitly told to do so with the update() method. I mean this sounds reasonable to me. I know I am missing something tho.

Comment: In C++ a pointer simply stores the address of a memory location. When you pass a pointer to a function, the location information is copied to that function, so even if you change your own pointer variable to point somewhere else, that will not affect the memory location you sent to the function.

Comment: Oh sure, I knew I missed something :D Thank you

Comment: Good luck with your project, and QStackedWidget is awesome. You can use it inside QtCreator's designer with ease.

Comment: Error in your code: use `deleteLater()` on `QObject`s, not `delete`.